# scroll page to the image | GITLAB

Tags: html, gitlab

i was wondering if it's possible in Gitlab to scroll page to the image after link clicked. I know it's possible to do scroll to the header f.e.

```
# header
some stuff...
[link](#header)
```

but with image it's not that easy. I tried some HTML because it should be supported according to the gitlab docs, but it's not working. Here the code that i tried:

```
<img src = "" id = "tag">
some stuff...
<a href = "#tag"> LINK </a>
```

Any ideas how to do that, or if it's even possible? I don't want to make headers in every place that i want jump to. If it's not maybe there is a trick to make headers invisible?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález could you explain in more details?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález well yeah... sorry for that, Actualy that was a typo indeed. So it should be `id = "tag"` and `<a href = "#tag">` but still it's not working.

Comment: Indeed, the Markdown renderer completely changes the structure of inline HTML and discards custom classes and IDs.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález exactly... do you have any idea how to cheat that?